# In Extjs 4.2 why does setValue() not update a textfield?

Tags: extjs

The following code seems to change the textfield value, because the AFTER alert shows the value as changed.

But when you look at the textfield in the form, it is blank???

```
var selectedItem = JSON.parse(CommonUtil.getSelectedRows(this.getSettingGrid()))[0];
alert("BEFORE: " + this.getSettingVcenter().queryById('txtName').getValue());
this.getSettingVcenter().queryById('txtName').setValue(selectedItem.name);
alert("AFTER: " + this.getSettingVcenter().queryById('txtName').getValue());
```

Comment: What does this.getSettingVcenter() return?

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I could think were that is possible is that you are not modifying the actual textfield but a copy of the object or something else.

**To fetch components in Ext you should use:**

```
var myTextField = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[itemId=someId]')[0];

myTextField.setValue("newValue");  //This is guaranteed to work
```

Also use:

```
console.log(yourObject); //this is to see the xtype of what your are modyfing the value, is it really the textfield?`
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query

Answer (score 0):

Making the textfield visible by using the setter method `setVisible(true)` after setting the value, made it show. I tried using `mytextField.hidden=false`; but did not work in afterrender.

Comment: It looks like [an answer similar to yours](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20550509/2343633) was posted a few months ago, but never excepted. Does your answer differ?